# to program GUI app , what will be the must user and developer frendly toolkit in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, user-friendly, easygui

i like to build desktop application , that will be must user friendly in view 
what i mean is that the look and feel will be natural in the way the user used to see windows 
apps . 
and this toolkit/framework to be as much as possible easy fast to develop from the developer side in c++ .

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows

Comment: The GUI toolkit in question is not as important as your GUI layout.  If Users have a hard time using your layout, the toolkit will not matter.  A difficult layout is difficult for a user regardless of whether you used wxWidgets, Qt, or Native Windows.  I would spend more time on the design of the GUI than the selection of the toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could we ask some more questions, what do you mean by user friendly(system integration easy keybingings/Accessibility)?

Which platforms(windows only?  You seem to indicate this, if so xp-7? 
Would fairly easy crossplatform support be a plus))?

Do you want a form builder? an ide? special libraries?

open source or closed source?
do you mind paying?

- qt is probably the most recommended
  option although there is also
- FLTK
- Juce
- wxwidgets
- gtk+(c based or use with gtk-- a c++ wrapper)

Comment: +1 - QT is probably the most warm and fluffy of the widely used GUI toolkits but a little more elaboration on what you're trying to do wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

It's a mature cross platform library that is easy to setup and to use. There's also a ton of resources available. The QT designer can also help you to quickly create your forms. There's even a visual studio plugin for it!

Comment: I see that Qt is now available under the LGPL license. Previously, it was only GPL or commercial, which was a show-stopper for me.

Comment: Yes, they modified that about 7 months ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out Qt is a great choice.  I went through the same search when I started coding C++ coming from Delphi, and this is where Qt shined.  It was the only option I found that offered a **complete** solution: GUI, DB access, cross-platform system calls (file-access, start-processes), XML, native platform configuration (text files in *nix, win-registry, etc), multi-threading.

It was a one-stop shop for everything I needed.